# How to avoid this hardcoded index.js when use webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, webpack

Tasks:

- **CSS**: compile .scss, add prefixes, minify and concat into **main.css**
- **JS**: minify and concat into **main.js**

We are using webpack and BEM.

Project structure:

```
static/
├── build
│   ├── main.css
│   └── main.js
└── src
    ├── blocks
    │   ├── a
    │   │   ├── a.js
    │   │   └── a.scss
    │   ├── b
    │   │   └── b.scss
    │   ├── c
    │   │   └── b.scss
    │   └── d
    │       ├── d.js
    │       └── d.scss
    └── index.js
```

**index.js** is entry point for webpack, this content:

```
// javascript
require("./a/a.js");
require("./d/d.js");

// scss
require('./a/a.scss');
require('./b/b.scss');
require('./c/c.scss');
require('./d/d.scss');
```

This approach is very bad, how to avoid this hardcoded **index.js** and automatically detect new .js and .scss files in **blocks** dir?

Can we define some globs (as in Gulp.js) for .js or .scss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.js**:

```
require.context('./blocks', true, /\.js$/);
require.context('./blocks', true, /\.scss$/);
```